# Is there any way to list one's own comments?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

This is related to my prior question, but the subject material is different enough to warrant its own question.

If one goes to one's own profile page, one can easily find a list of their own questions, answers, tags, badges, etc, but no historical list of comments they've made. Have I simply missed a mechanism by which one might find such a list?

I understand, of course, that I can find some of those comments indirectly (in cases wherein someone has responded to such a comment) by poring through my Inbox. The Inbox is a poor substitute, though, for a complete ordered historical list.

If the site software lacks such a mechanism, that might be a handy feature addition. Speaking for my own case, I'd like to review comments I've made over the course of, say, the last two weeks as part of a self-audit. It might be handy, too, for the user who would like to review their own comments for other reasons - second thoughts, additional inspirations, followup questions, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. Just go to your user page, select the "Activity" tab, and then the "Comments" tab under that.